# How to clear all selected items in a SELECT input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am think this should be fairly easy, but struggling a bit ... I have a `SELECT` input element that allows the user to select multiple items. I would like to provide a mechanism for them to clear all selected items, probably will just be a `SPAN` tag or something similar.

Anyway ... using jQuery, how I would I clear the selection on the `SELECT` input element so no items are selected.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In the case of a `<select multiple>` the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function takes/returns an array, so you can simply pass in an empty array to clear the selection, like this:

```
$("#selectID").val([]);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pjSPy/).

Comment: @Deepu - it still works here in every major browser...I'd check your console for a user script interfering, possibly loading a conflicting version of jQuery.

Comment: Nick I want to [second button](http://jsfiddle.net/pjSPy/394/) So that when user press `Reset to previous` button then old selected option select back. Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan store the array of values like `var old = $('#selectId').val();` and restore it via `$('#selectID').val(old);`...just save whenever you want and restore on the button press.

Comment: Got it!!..I am kinda a new guy in web stuffs. Thanks Very much.

Comment: $("#selectID").val([]) would be slightly better because it doesn't create a new array unnecessarily and accomplishes the same goal.

Answer (score 13):

This worked to clear all selected options for me..

```
$("#selectListName").prop('selectedIndex', -1)
```

The select list looked like

```
<select multiple='multiple' id='selectListName'> 
  <option>1</option> 
  <option>2</option> 
  <option>3</option> 
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use index number which option you want to select. 
In my case the first option was "Please choose", so i used $("#selectListName").prop('selectedIndex', 0) in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Try:
    // Just put # before select to fix this. Works perfect.
    $("#select option:selected").each(function () {
        $(this).remove(); //or whatever else
    });

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me...

```
$('#my-Select').val('').trigger('change');
```

This works on almost any input type.

Answer (score 5):

Only this worked for me:-

```
$("#selectid").find('option').attr("selected",false) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

i try something like

```
$("#my-Select").find('option').attr("selected","") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select id='select1' ></select>
<input type= 'button' value = 'Clear Selection' id = 'remove' />

$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#remove').click(function() {  
     return $('#select1 option:selected').remove(); 
   });
 });
```

Comment: wouldn't this remove all the selected items rather than just clear the selection?

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe 

$('#mySelect option').each(function(i, e)
{
   e.selected = false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
$("#selectID").empty();
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score -3):

Better than this, you can use:

```
$("#selectID").empty();
```

That works on almost anything in the DOM.

Comment: This removes all options of all selects and not the selected values.