# Remove Validation for Reset button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have below form , once we select "Designer", than only it will display options to select "Order Number" & once if select "Order Number" than only it will allow to select "Product" , where "Product" is multi-select box.

[image]

Assume i selected "Designer" & "Order Number" , than **when i click Reset button , its doing validation that its asking to fill "Product"** values , its fine for submit buttton, but it should not do validation for "RESET" button.

I am trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748303/how-to-clear-all-selected-items-in-a-select-input-using-jquery) but still its not working....

Here all option values are fetching dynamically from php code as below.

[image]

Product is multi-select box

[image]

**form**

```
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="update_paidstatus.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> Designer </td>     
        <td>
          <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name="designer_id" id="designer_id">
            <option value="">Select Designer</option>
            <?php while($data = $stmt->fetch())  { if($data['type']=="admin")continue;?>
              <option value="<?php echo $data['userID'];?>"><?php echo $data['name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>  
        </td> 

        <td><p id="error_para1" ></p></td>
    </tr> 

      <tr>
        <td>
           Order Number: 
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id">
            <option value="">Select Order</option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </td>
         <td><p id="error_para2" ></p></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>
          Product 
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">
          <select id="mySelect">
            <option>Select Products</option>
          </select>

        </div>
       </td>
        <td><p id="error_para3" ></p></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <hr/>

<input type="hidden" name="dproduct_id" id="dproduct_id" value=""/> 
   <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="btn-signup" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
  <button formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">RESET</button>

  </form>
```

**Script**

```
function validate()
{
 // alert("d");
 var error="";
 var designer_id = document.getElementById( "designer_id" );
 if( designer_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Designer";
  document.getElementById( "error_para1" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
 var error="";
 var dproduct_ids = document.getElementById( "dproduct_ids" );

 if( dproduct_ids.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Product";
  document.getElementById( "error_para3" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
 var error="";
 var designerorder_id = document.getElementById( "designerorder_id" );
 if( designerorder_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Order";
  document.getElementById( "error_para2" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
 var error="";
 var commission = document.getElementById( "commission" );
 alert(commission.value );
 if(commission.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please add commission";
  document.getElementById( "error_para5" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
 var error="";
 var Duedate = document.getElementById( "Duedate" );
 if(Duedate.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Designer";
  document.getElementById( "error_para6" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
  else
 {
  return true;
 }
}


$(document).ready(

  /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
  function () {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
      changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
    });
  }

);
  function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;    
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }
  function getProductDetail(e)
  {    
    var productId = $("#dproductselect option:selected").attr("class");  
    var finalstrig=productId.split(",");

    var select='';
    select+='<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">';

    for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
    {
      if(finalstrig[i]!=0)
      {
        select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
      }
    }
    select +='</select>';   
    document.getElementById('productnumbers').innerHTML =select;
    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.test').fSelect();
    });
})(jQuery);

  }
     <!-- reset -->
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#mySelect").val([]);
});
```

Note : I tried lot before posting here, also i am new to this programming world.... please help me....

Comment: The "RESET" button is also a submit button -> `<input type="reset" value="RESET" />`

Comment: @Andreas i want to remove validation only for `reset button`, so i am using this code for  reset  button : `$("button").click(function() {
    $("#mySelect").val([]);
});`

Comment: @abcd  do what `@Andreas`  said

Comment: @Andreas i tried that before, but what happened is once i click on reset button still `product` values remained as like : http://prnt.sc/db4285

Comment: @Anant  i tried that before, but what happened is once i click on reset button still `product` values remained as like : http://prnt.sc/db4285

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you dynamically insert some html elements, so just a `input` tag with a type of `reset` can not resolve your problem, you also need register a listener to remove these additional elements when you click reset input button.

Replace your reset `button` tag with following HTML `input` tag and in your Script replace your reset code with the following Script code.

HTML:

```
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id='button_reset' formnovalidate="formnovalidate" value="RESET"/>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
  $("#button_reset").click(function() { 
    $("#productnumbers").html('<select id="mySelect"><option>Select Products</option></select>');
  });
});
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: The value of attribute `multiple` of you `select` in `getProductDetail` function wrong, the value of `multiple` should be `true` of `false`, it's type is Boolean.

Comment: @ abcd Can you give a jsfiddle or codepen link so we can see what happened there?

Comment: @abcd In fact options has been removed when you click `RESET` button, but the view of multiple options you implement is by some `div` tags, not the native `select` tag, so when click `RESET` you should remove those additional div tags, just do this as above, i updated.

Comment: I updated code above, this should fix `Order Number` selected but `Product` can't be selected again in last version.

Comment: once we select  `Designer` & click on `reset` button its not working......

Comment: You want to reset ALL forms data when click `RESET`? or just reset products which have been selected?

Comment: its working fine with your code but one issue is when we click on `reset` button its hiding `select products` text. also, as you said i tried @DarshanPrajapati  code , but when i click on `reset` button, values of `product` still remain without resetting....

Comment: @DarshanPrajapati code, you also need to register an event listener for your reset `input` tag, giving it an `id` property and use code ·$("RESET_INPUT_ID_HERE").click(function() { 
  $("#productnumbers").html('<select id="mySelect"><option>Select Products</option></select>');
});· to init your view, i will update the code.

Comment: U'r welcome, maybe you need to learn a little more knowledge about html and javascript someday  : )

Comment: you are right, not little bit, need to learn lot, hope i will get atleast 1% knowledge of you one day :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128930/discussion-between-abcd-and-catssay).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" value="RESET"/>
```

Try This Code For Reset Button

Comment: i tried that before, it will solve current problem,  but one more issue will create, that is once i click on reset button still product values will remain as like : http://prnt.sc/db4285

Answer (score 0):

Make Button type as "button". Try this..

```
 <button type="button" onClick="resetSelect()" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">RESET</button>
```

Then in script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resetSelect() {
  $("#mySelect").fSelect("reload");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: did you include onClick="resetSelect()"    ??