# How to clear all selected items in a dropdpwn?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

My question is related to Angular and Typescript. My problem is quite tricky. I've created a dropdown menu with 3 items. But I'm not creating it using `select` tag of HTML. I'm using my company's toolkit. Which is just a wrapper around `primeng` components with our font and our color scheme. They call it `PLK toolkit`. Their code have a bug. It is not clearing the previously selected item. Here is their sample dropdown code (i feel it is ok to share the code because it is few lines of plain html only and that too written by me):

**Note:** In below code,  `plk-dropdown` is like `select` tag, while `plk-option` is like `option` tag. There's nothing special about it.

```
<plk-dropdown [(ngModel)]="fruit" name="fruit">
    <plk-option [value]="'apple'">Apple</plk-option>
    <plk-option [value]="'pear'">Pear</plk-option>
    <plk-option [value]="'melon'">Melon</plk-option>
</plk-dropdown>
```

So, when I click it first time it is good.But after first click it keeps on selecting the other options along with previous. I looked into their code:

**dropdown.js**

```
DropDownComponent.prototype.writeValue = function (value) {
    if (this.options) {
        this.selectOptionByValue(value);
    }
};
```

and I fixed this bug by adding 1 line of code:

```
DropDownComponent.prototype.writeValue = function (value) {
  if (this.options) {
      this.clearSelectedOptions(); // THIS I ADDED
      this.selectOptionByValue(value);
  }
};
```

Now the compoenent is working but the problem is that I can't make changes to their `js` file. Firstly, I'm not supposed to do so. Secondly, if in future we update our repositories, that bug will come back.

Is there any way I can fix this with my typescript code. I cant implement `jquery` in between. I tried this:

[How to clear all selected items in a SELECT input using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748303/how-to-clear-all-selected-items-in-a-select-input-using-jquery)

Please help me. I'm blocked because of this. I really need help.

Comment: I reported this bug 1 month ago. It seems they are not interested.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example for this

Comment: @AkhilAravind. Sir I would happily do that. But that's company's code. I'll have to import a lots of libraries that Stackblitz will not support. It works on our proxy only. :-(

Comment: is something like this possible `<plk-dropdown [(ngModel)]="fruit" name="fruit" id="ddlFruit" onclick="clearddl(this)">` where you can call a javascript function and clear **rendered** dropdown list with id=ddlFruit

Comment: give me 2 mins please . I'll quickly try this.

Comment: @Tanzeel okay bro, try to make a stackblitz sample with minimal code, to reproduce the error. just the drop down part is enough

Comment: @AkhilAravind. Sir I tried making one. But it is working fine there because I'm using `select` and `option` tags. The problem is not the HTML tag. The problem is with our stupid toolkit.

Comment: @Tanzeel bro then you have to find a solution your own :(

Comment: @AkhilAravind. Its been more than 1 month i reported this bug. Sir, This has spoiled my time and efforts :-(

Comment: @AkhilAravind. Can i just override that method in my typescript file and make necessary changes. I don't know. I'm just asking if it is possible.

Comment: @Tanzeel you can do anything in your own component

Answer (score 1):

I use a null option so when the dropdown has no values unselected option is selected , I thing it 's related to primeng the set the first option as selected even the value don't match with ngModel property I have create a demo to show this but so far that how we solve abd this will give to the use an option to undo the selection in case this was not required.

```js
<plk-dropdown [(ngModel)]="fruit" name="fruit">
    <plk-option [value]="null">Unselected</plk-option>
    <plk-option [value]="'apple'">Apple</plk-option>
    <plk-option [value]="'pear'">Pear</plk-option>
    <plk-option [value]="'melon'">Melon</plk-option>
</plk-dropdown>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropedown-clear-selecteditem)

Comment: I'll quickly try this. I'll get back to you shortly.